# Bootstrap dropdowns in ReactJS, only one open at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a page contains multiple Bootstrap Cards and each card is a component and each card footer is also a component. Card Footer contains buttons. When you click on a button, drop down will be opened like below

[image]

At any point of time when I click on a button, other drop downs should be in closed state. But its happening like this...

[image]

Requirement: One more thing is when I click on the same button, the respective drop down should be closed.

Requirement: When I click on any item inside drop down the respective drop down should be closed

My Architecture is like below

[image]

### HOME PAGE COMPONENT CODE -START

```js
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      activatedIdStoredInParent: ""
    };
  }
  toggleCountersMenu = (name) => {
    var name1 = name;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        activatedIdStoredInParent: name1
      }
    });
  } 

  render() {
   
    const products = this.state.items.map((item, index) => {     
      return <div>
        <Card
          product={item}
          activatedIdStoredInParent={this.state.activatedIdStoredInParent}
          toggleCountersMenu={this.toggleCountersMenu}
        >
        </Card>;
      </div>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="card-columns">
          {products}
        </div>
      </div >
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

### HOME PAGE COMPONENT CODE - END

### CARD COMPONENT CODE - START

```js
class Card extends React.Component {
    handleActionClick = (name) => {
        this.props.toggleCountersMenu(name);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div key={this.props.product.name}>
                <CardHeader product={this.props.product}  />
                <CardBody product={this.props.product}  />
                <CardFooter
                    product={this.props.product}                    
                    onActionItemClick={this.handleActionClick}
                    activatedIdStoredInParent={this.props.activatedIdStoredInParent}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```

### CARD FOOTER COMPONENT CODE - START

```js
class CardFooter extends React.Component {

    handleActionItemClick = (name) => {
        this.props.onActionItemClick(name);
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Card Footer Drop Down comp rendered');
        return (
            <div className=" card-footer text-center">
                <ButtonDropdown text="F" className="danger"
                    product={this.props.product}
                    onActionItemClick={this.handleActionItemClick}
                    activatedIdStoredInParent={this.props.activatedIdStoredInParent}
                ></ButtonDropdown>            
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CardFooter;
```

### ButtonDropdown COMPONENT CODE - START

```js
class ButtonDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            show: ' none',
            localActivatedId: 'none'
        }
    }
    toggleOpen = (e) => {
        var name = e.target.name;

        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            var item = {
                localActivatedId: name
            }
            if (props.activatedIdStoredInParent === name) {
                if (prevState.show === ' show') {
                    item.show = ' none';
                }
                else {
                    item.show = ' show';
                }
            }
            return item;
        });
        this.props.onActionItemClick(name);
    }

    numberClick = (e) => {
        var qty = e.target.innerText;
        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            var item = {
                show: ' none'
            }
            return item;
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="btn-group" >
                <button type="button" className={`btn btn-${this.props.className}  mr-1`} name={this.props.product.name + '$$' + this.props.text} onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
                    {this.props.text} (classAdded={this.state.show})
                </button>
                
                <div className={`dropdown-menu ${this.state.show}`}>
                    <span className="dropdown-item cursor-pointer " onClick={this.numberClick}>
                        -1
                    </span>
                    <span className="dropdown-item cursor-pointer" onClick={this.numberClick}>
                        -2
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>



        );
    }
}

export default ButtonDropdown;
```

When I add multiple buttonDropdown components in Card Footer the end product is like this. How can I close other dropdowns.

[image]

I would like to know is my architecture is correct.. I am not using Redux/Flux etc..

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but compliments on your in-depth explanation and formatting :)!

Comment: Any reason to not use `DropdownButton` component from `react-bootstrap`? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle, in order to update your state's property that is opening the dropdown.
I don't know if it's the `open` or `show` property that displays the content of the dropdown but here's my logic.

```
class ButtonDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // 
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const name = this.props.product.name + '$$' + this.props.text;

    if (prevProps.activatedIdStoredInParent !== this.props.activatedIdStoredInParent && this.props.activatedIdStoredInParent !== name) {
      this.closeDropDown();
    }
  }

  closeDropDown = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  toggleOpen = (e) => {
    //
  }

  numberClick = (e) => {
   //
  }

  render() {
   //
  }
}

export default ButtonDropdown;
```

Comment: Hi Soupette, Thank You for your answer. It worked. if you write in componentDidUpdate , it will call each time and it will be performance issue right. what do you say.. can you pls explain a bit..

Comment: You can use a `PureComponent` to increase the performances. Regarding the use of componentDidUpdate I don't see another way to open and close your component using the current architecture unless you get rid of the state and use only the parent container's props.

Comment: Thank you for your response. "unless you get rid of the state and use only the parent container's props". What exactly is this architecture, can you please show me.

Comment: `const name = const name = this.props.product.name + '$$' + this.props.text;`
`const show = name === this.props.activatedIdStoredInParent`
And then use the show variable in your className

Comment: If i remove this  "this.props.activatedIdStoredInParent !== name" its going to infinite loop. If my json is having more objects like 10000, is this code feasible?